# BottomSheet height is 0 after first expand

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am trying to calculate the height of my bottom sheet when expanded:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior" >
    <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
        android:id="@+id/compose_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView>
</FrameLayout>

bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(binding.searchBottomSheet)
bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN
bottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(object : bottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
   override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
      when (newState) {
         BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED -> {
            Log.i("Logger", "Bottom sheet height is ${bottomSheet.height}")
         }
      }
   }

   override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {}
})
```

Programmatically expand the bottom sheet:

```
searchBottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
```

The callback is called only once when expanded and the height is 0.  If I collapse and re-expand the height is correct.

I suspect that this is due to the bottom sheet state changed callback firing before the compose view is laid out and has a height.  Is there any way around this, I need to set padding on another layout based on the sheet height.